# Deleting an entire record in a XML column

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have a table called `XMLTable` that contain one `XMLcolumn` called `XMLData`. `XMLData` contains the following:

```
<Product>
  <Products>
    <ProductID>9</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Mishi Kobe Niku</ProductName>
    <UnitPrice>97.0000</UnitPrice>
  </Products>
  <Products>
    <ProductID>29</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Thüringer Rostbratwurst</ProductName>
    <UnitPrice>123.7900</UnitPrice>
  </Products>
  <Products>
    <ProductID>38</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Côte de Blaye</ProductName>
    <UnitPrice>263.5000</UnitPrice>
  </Products>
</Product>
```

I need to delete an entire record for a specific ProductID such as:

```
<Products>
    <ProductID>9</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Mishi Kobe Niku</ProductName>
    <UnitPrice>97.0000</UnitPrice>
  </Products>
```

I tried using the following code:

```
UPDATE XMLTable
SET
    XMLData.modify('delete
(/Products/ProductID[ProductID="9"]/ProductID)') 

UPDATE XMLTable
SET
    XMLData.modify('delete
(/Product/Products/ProductName[ProductName="Mishi Kobe Niku"]/ProductName)') 

UPDATE XMLTable
SET
    XMLData.modify('delete
(/Product/Products/UnitPrice[UnitPrice="97.0000"]/UnitPrice)')
```

I can insert new records and modify data but I can't get it to delete an entire record.

Comment: Are you looking for a TSQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

The following works in TSQL

```
UPDATE XMLTable SET XMLData.modify('
  delete /Product/Products[ProductID=9]')
```

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45e10/3